# bee is not executable

Tags: go, beego

Using ubuntu15.go get github.com/beego/bee

```
root@hao:/var/www/go/bin# ls
bee
root@hao:/var/www/go/bin# bee
未找到 'bee' 命令.(Bee command not found)
```

profile:

```
export GOPATH=/var/www/go
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export PATH=$GOROOT/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: If GOPATH/bin is not in your PATH then the result is to be expected.

Comment: I think you can follow this [link](https://github.com/beego/bee) and you can enter the `/usr/local/go/bin` to find the `bee` .If you cant find it ,you should sure the `bee` path. By the way, I think you can join a qq group to ask questions about entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first check that your binary is executable (run `ls -l) and check that "x" is part of the permission of your user (if you're not sure, just run`chmod +x bee)

Second, to execute a binary in unix you should type `./bee`